# How to use Axon with Vert.X

Tags: vert.x, cqrs, event-sourcing, axon

I have a CQRS/Eventsourcing architecture with 3 microservices. I implemented 2 microservices with vert.x 4 and I implemented CQRS/Eventsourcing without framework to improve my knowledge of this type of architecture. For the third microservice I would like to use AxonIq Framework but I have a problem with Aggregate annotation because it's not avalaible with vert.x but only with Spring.
I implemented a Spring microservice using Axon and everything work fine but I would like to know if someone can help me for use vert.x with AxonIq ? If anyone know a workaround for this problem ?

Thank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Axon Farmework provide something called `Configuration API`. You can have a look at the [Configuration class](https://github.com/AxonFramework/AxonFramework/blob/master/config/src/main/java/org/axonframework/config/Configuration.java) but for making use of it, you need a [Configurer](https://github.com/AxonFramework/AxonFramework/blob/master/config/src/main/java/org/axonframework/config/DefaultConfigurer.java), which will provide you all means of configuring your components!

On the ref-guide, you also have several examples of how to do the configuration using the API or Srring Boot. Example for Commands can be found [here](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/axon-framework/axon-framework-commands/configuration).

To help a bit more, I can also share a small project I made using Dropwizard and Axon Framework, meaning no Spring was used and all the Configuration was done through the API.
You can find it here https://github.com/lfgcampos/axon-playground/tree/master/chat-getting-started-dropwizard

Comment: FWIW, I don't think Axon and Vert.x will work all that well together. Vert.x is an asynchronous framework, while as best as I can tell, Axon is entirely synchronous. You'd have to wrap all your blocking calls to Axon APIs in `executeBlocking` calls to keep them from blocking the Vert.x event loop. Even that may not handle all use-cases (like implementing an Axon Command Handler)

Comment: The argument "Axon is entirely synchronous" is incorrect, by the way. Nonetheless, being mindful of Vert.x's approach when using Axon's message-driven solution is a fair recommendation. When Axon Framework is or is not synchronous, very much depends on the infrastructure configuration. Thus, the chosen buses and gateways for commands, events, and queries.